# Calculate between two statements

Tags: mysql, sql

I got two statements and I want to calculate their values. Both values have to be calculated 5 - 5 = ( I want to see the answer 0 )

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Aantal stoelen geboekt'
FROM Boekingsregel, Vlucht
WHERE Boekingsregel.Vlucht_Vlucht_Id = Vlucht.Vlucht_Id
AND Vlucht_Datum = '2017-04-10';

SELECT min(Vliegtuig_Aantal_Stoelen) AS 'Max aantal stoelen'
FROM Vliegtuig;
```

Comment: Both the query result have integer output ? and you want to check just `@query_one_output - @query_two_output` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I do not see any relation of the two queries you also should not use an alias with spaces. Make your alias as short as possible but can define what value it holds, but since this is your query you know better than I do.

As for your problem you can combine the two queries into one something like this:

```
SELECT BR.`Aantal stoelen geboekt` - VT.`Max aantal stoelen` AS TheResult 
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS `Aantal stoelen geboekt` 
FROM Boekingsregel, Vlucht 
WHERE Boekingsregel.Vlucht_Vlucht_Id = Vlucht.Vlucht_Id 
AND Vlucht_Datum = '2017-04-10') BR,
(SELECT min(Vliegtuig_Aantal_Stoelen) AS `Max aantal stoelen` FROM Vliegtuig) VT;
```

NOTE: Not tested I just type it here.

If this is not what you are looking for then maybe you should explain your requirements in greater detail so dhat everyone can understand and will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

First, learn to use proper `JOIN` syntax.

Second, combine these in the `FROM` clause.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS AantalStoelenGeboekt, vt.MaxAantalStoelen
FROM Boekingsregel b JOIN
     Vlucht v
     ON b.Vlucht_Vlucht_Id = v.Vlucht_Id CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT min(Vliegtuig_Aantal_Stoelen) AS MaxAantalStoelen
      FROM Vliegtuig
     ) vt
WHERE v.Vlucht_Datum = '2017-04-10';
```

Note:  MySQL allows this syntax.  Perhaps a cleaner way is to use an aggregation function on `MaxAantalStoelen`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS AantalStoelenGeboekt,
       MAX(vt.MaxAantalStoelen) as MaxAantalStoelen
FROM Boekingsregel b JOIN
     Vlucht v
     ON b.Vlucht_Vlucht_Id = v.Vlucht_Id CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT min(Vliegtuig_Aantal_Stoelen) AS MaxAantalStoelen
      FROM Vliegtuig
     ) vt
WHERE v.Vlucht_Datum = '2017-04-10';
```